# How to mock Express Response.setHeader function using Jest?

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, jestjs

I created a custom Express middleware checking if the request content type is JSON. If that's not the case, the server responds with a 415 and a custom error object

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";

function enforceContentTypeApplicationJson() {
  return (request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    if (!request.is("application/json")) {
      response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      response.statusCode = 415;

      const actualContentType = request.get("Content-Type") ?? "";
      const errorResult = {
        isSuccessful: false,
        error: `Expected Content-Type 'application/json' but got '${actualContentType}'.`,
      };

      response.json(errorResult);

      return;
    }

    next();
  };
}
```

I want to test this middleware using Jest. My first test is

```
  it("responds with status code 415 if header 'Content-Type' is not 'application/json'.", () => {
    const contentType = "multipart/form-data";
    const mockRequest: Partial<Request> = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": contentType,
      },
      is: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => false),
      get: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => contentType),
    };
    const mockResponse: Partial<Response> = {
      json: jest.fn(),
      setHeader: jest.fn().mockImplementation(function (name, value) {
        (this as unknown as Response).setHeader(name, value);
      }),
    };

    const nextFunction: NextFunction = jest.fn();

    const expectedResponse = {
      isSuccessful: false,
      error: `Expected Content-Type 'application/json' but got '${contentType}'.`,
    };

    const middleware = enforceContentTypeApplicationJson();

    middleware(mockRequest as Request, mockResponse as Response, nextFunction);

    expect(mockResponse.statusCode).toBe(415);
    // expect(mockResponse.getHeader('Content-Type')).toBe('application/json');
    // expect(mockResponse.getHeaders?.()["Content-Type"]).toBe('application/json');
    // expect(mockResponse.getHeader?.("Content-Type")).toBe('application/json');
    expect(mockResponse.json).toBeCalledWith(expectedResponse);
  });
```

but I'm struggling with `mockResponse.setHeader` because the testrunner fails with the error

> this.setHeader is not a function

How do I mock the `setHeader` function for the `Response` type? I want to provide a mock implementation because later on I also want to provide a mock implementation for the `getHeader` function to make assertions on the response content-type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow functions don't have their own bindings to `this`. I don't see any reason to mock implementation for `mockResponse.setHeader` like that. `mockResponse.setHeader = jest.fn()` is enough, like `mockResponse.json()` method.

---

**UPDATE**

I don't see any reason to store the headers and get them later for assertion. The `mockResponse` object is a mock, not the real response object, There is no need to store the headers in `mockResponse`.

You can make an assertion like this:

```js
mockResponse.setHeader.toHaveBeenCalledWith('Content-Type', 'application/json')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need a mock implementation because later on I would like to make assertions on the response content-type

Comment: @baitendbidz Please edit your question and show the code for that assertion. Make it clearly

Comment: I updated my question ( sample code ). I want to test that the response is sending json content.